# Integral about lengh o f an arc

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I can't find a way to solve this:
$$
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \sqrt{8sen^2(t)cos^2(t)}dt
$$

The integral is to calculate the length of an arc, by parametric equations.
The answer is $\sqrt{2}$, but i'm finding $-\sqrt{2}$ instead.
Can you solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't $(-2)^2 = +4$?

Comment: No limits, no answer.

Comment: Ins't $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ (assuming $x \geq 0$)?

Comment: Please don't change the question each time you receive a hint (putting in the limits is fine, but don't go from $(-2\sin(t)\cos(t))^2 + (2\sin(t)\cos(t))^2 = 8\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t)$)...and I have no idea what $sen$ is?  I'm assuming you mean $\sin(t)$.

Comment: The cosine is negative between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$, so our square root is $-2\sqrt{2}\cos t\sin t$.

Comment: but $cos^2(t)$ is positive

Comment: @Bruno Yes because a negative squared always gives a positive.  The problem is that when you take the square root, you should really do the following: $x^\frac{1}{2} = \pm\sqrt{x}$ where $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.  So you actually get: $\sqrt{\cos^2(t)} = \left|\cos(t)\right|$ and _you_ have to enforce the absolute value (it doesn't happen automagically) which means you really need $-\cos(t)$ over this interval.  You may want to look up the piecewise definition for the absolute value function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second quadrant $\;\frac\pi2<x<\pi\;$, we have that

$$\sin x>0\,,\,\,\,\cos x<0\implies \sqrt{8\sin^2x\cos^2x}=\sqrt8\sin x(-\cos x)=-2\sqrt2\sin x\cos x\implies$$

$$-2\sqrt2\int\limits_{\frac\pi2}^\pi\sin x\cos x\;dx=\left.-2\sqrt2\frac12\sin^2x\right|_{-\frac\pi2}^\pi=-\sqrt2\left(\sin\pi-\sin\frac\pi2\right)=\sqrt2$$